# Lock and unlock cells based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2016 file, where I'm trying to lock and unlock cells based another cell value, which is running a index match formula as this is changing depending on drop down chosen.

So if J13 shows "Accepting" then D13:G13 are not locked and able to edited.

If showing "Refusing" then D13:G13 are locked.

J13 is an index match formula as this is looking up in table to get the collect date of refusing and accepting are change based on dropdown option chosen by user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below code in the sheet which you need to monitor. The below code will check if the text in cell is Accepting on every selection change. If the condition passes then it will lock the mentioned range.Use appropriate password to protect and unprotect your worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="pass"
Call lockAllCellsInSheet(ActiveSheet.Name)
    If Range("J13").Text = "Accepting" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D13:G13").Locked = True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("D13:G13").Locked = False
    End If
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="pass"
End Sub
```

This is a generic code to lock all the cells. Alternatively what you can do is lock all the cells be default and remove the below code block and also the function call in the above code.

```
Sub lockAllCellsInSheet(SheetName As String)
  lastCol = Sheets(SheetName).Range("a1").End(xlToRight).Column
  Lastrow = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
  Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1", Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Lastrow, lastCol)).Locked = False
End Sub
```

If you want to monitor specific Range only the add the below code in the selection change code

```
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("A1:B13") 'Range to be monitored
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
    End If
```

Comment: The first code is not working for me. It seems to be locking cells either if accepting and refusing